# Forcing a DIV to cover entire row using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using a framework which is generating 3 div tags. These three div tags cover one row on the page.
It looks like the first div covers 25% of the row and 2 div covers 25% of the row and the third div covers 50% of the row. I have access to the css class which third div is utilizing which looks like this:

```
.dataTables_processing {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 125px;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #eee;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

**Is there any way to modify this class to make it cover the entire row?**

[image]

Comment: Might be just a typo, but classes have a `.` before their name in CSS, but in your code it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried adding `width: 100%` and removing `left: 50%`?

Comment: By 'making it cover the entire row'. you mean only the third div should exist?

Comment: @DJDavid98  I have tried `width:100%` but that did not helped me. But if I remove the div that appears before the third div, everything works fine. The first two div are generated by Jquery DataTable.

Comment: Post you markup as well. Also consider providing an online example to demonstrate the issue in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding :

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
width:100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
display: block;
width: 100%;
min-width: 100% !important;
```

Comment: Tried but without any luck :(

Comment: @SharpCoder R u using smth like twitter bootstrap?

Comment: I am using Jquery DataTable. Along with changes you suggested changing  `position: absolute !important;` helped. Voting up your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have some div that each one takes a row and you want them to align vertically, use bootstrap and you can do something like this:

```
<div style='display: flex; flex-direction: column;'>
  <div class='row'> my content to take a row </div>
  <div class='row'> my content to take second row </div>
  <div class='row'> my content to take a third</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.